# Doing something every x minutes in Python gives the same answer

Tags: python

this is the code:

```
import datetime
import schedule
import time

local = datetime.datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
hour = str(local)

def job():
    if hour.startswith('16'):
        print("Hi! It's ", local)
    else:
        print("nope!")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I'm trying to repeat **job** (if current hour starts with 16 then say *hi it's local* , if it doesn't say *nope*) every 10 minutes, but it gives the same response every time, example, started the code at 16:40, gives right answer (hi it's local) but after 17:00 it still gives the same answer with the old time instead of just saying *nope* (or the right time), I'm not sure if the schedule code is right, need some help, ty!

Comment: `hour` is a global string value, set just once. It will not change with each call to `job()`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, how would I execute what I'm trying to do, is there another method?

Comment: You're never updating `local` or `hour`. You should place them both inside `job` so they update every time you call `job`.

Comment: If you want to check the **current** time, then call `datetime.datetime.now()` inside your `job` function. Note that `time` objects have an `hour` attribute, that's a much better value to test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, notice the reading of current time inside the job function:

```
from datetime import datetime
import schedule
import time

def job():
    local = datetime.now().time().replace(microsecond=0)
    if local.hour == 16:
        print("Hi! It's ", local)
    else:
        print("nope!")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: You're printing `time` which is the time module. I think you mean to be printing `local`.

Comment: @Blckknght You're right, I made a boo boo. Editing it. Thanks!